# Dynamically changing the labels of Bootstrap 4 Toggles

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am currently using [Bootstrap 4 Toggle](https://gitbrent.github.io/bootstrap4-toggle/#)'s on my webpage and can't seem to find a way to dynamically change the labels on those toggles during runtime.

My goal ist to have a toggle-switch that when activated shows a countdown that shows the time until it automatically reverts to 'off'. So on default the state is 'off'. When activated, it should display: 'on (5:00)' -> 'on (4:59)' -> 'on (4:58)' etc. Once the timer hits 0:00, the state will be reverted to 'off' again.

Here is a runnable code snippet to play around with:

```js
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
  $('#mytoggle').data("on", "new label text")
  console.log($('#mytoggle').data("on"))
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="mytoggle" type="checkbox" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="lg">
<button id="mybutton">Change label</button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

What I want to achieve here is that when clicking on the "Change label"-Button the "on" label text of the toggle switch changes to "new label text". Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: There's no built in way to do what you ask. You would need to select the elements Bootstrap has wrapped the label text in directly and update it using `text()`. *However* changing the label of a control at runtime is a bit of a code smell - which is why it's not natively supported by the toggle control out of the box. For what reason do you need to do this? There may be a better method to achieve whatever it is you need to do.

Comment: I updated my question with a description of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Bind data dynamically on data-on and data-off

Example: Suppose if you are using angular framework then you will achieve it by interpolation

Comment: I tried doing that acutally. Since I am using Scala.js, I used scalatags & scalatags-rx for that, but it still does not change the labels on the toggle switches. Anyway if it doesn't even work using jQuery, I am pretty sure it won't work with reactive data-bindings.

Comment: Can you please post your code as an example somewhere?

Comment: The setup is a bit tedious, but I posted a much simpler version with my original question.